# How do I add async=false in python to a Gstreamer splitmuxsink element Audio/video/H264 combined

Tags: python, audio, video, gstreamer, h.264

Gstreamer 1.8.2 installed on an embedded device using a C920. Debian linux. I have a nice Gstreamer pipeline that uses the new splitmuxsink and almost works.
I do have splitmuxsink working on a 'basic pipeline' nicely.

The first pipeline works and writes one long file mp4, audio and video and at the same time passes a preview jpeg stream to a separately handled appsink which works. Hope this is useful in any case for someone.

```
    self.pipeline=Gst.parse_launch('uvch264src auto-start=true iframe-period=1000 name=src1 src1.vfsrc ! queue  ! appsink drop=true name=asink max-buffers=2 emit-signals=true sync=false src1.vidsrc ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! queue ! h264parse ! muxout.video_0   alsasrc do-timestamp=true device="plughw:CARD=C920,DEV=0" ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=32000,depth=16,channels=1 ! queue ! voaacenc ! queue ! aacparse ! muxout.audio_0 mp4mux name=muxout ! filesink sync=false location=%s' % location1)
```

But when I convert the filesink to a 'splitmuxsink', it only creates previews, and does not start the file recording side of the stream. I do not know how (programmatically in Python) to set the attributes of splitmuxsink to replicate the sync=false that I am doing on the filesink plugin. Do I attach to a pad on splitmuxsink, or somehow setup the sink=xxx label and get_static_pad or element to then adjust the properties of that 'child' element? I believe this problem is what is causing the file splitting part of the pipeline to fail. I am looking for something like: 
[How to resume playing after paused using gstreamer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547500/how-to-resume-playing-after-paused-using-gstreamer)
based on this answer:         [gstreamer pipeline with VADER element stalls on PAUSE when used with a tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504257/gstreamer-pipeline-with-vader-element-stalls-on-pause-when-used-with-a-tee)

Pipeline v2 (runs the appsink side, but splitmuxsink stays paused)

```
    self.pipeline=Gst.parse_launch('uvch264src auto-start=true async-handling=false message-forward=true iframe-period=1000 name=src1 src1.vfsrc ! queue  ! appsink drop=true name=asink max-buffers=200 emit-signals=true sync=true src1.vidsrc ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! queue  ! h264parse ! queue ! splitmuxsink max-size-time=20000000000 max-size-bytes=5000000 name=muxout location=video2%05d.mp4  alsasrc do-timestamp=true device="plughw:CARD=C920,DEV=0" ! audio/x-raw,forma=S16LE,rate=32000,depth=16,channels=1 ! queue ! voaacenc ! queue ! aacparse ! muxout.audio_0
```

As you can see, pipeline v2 has no explicit reference to sync=false as splitmuxsink does not have that property. And so that side does not start after PAUSED.

I am sure this is just going to be a tiny adjustment to create the right label and set its attributes after my

```
    self.muxp = self.pipeline.get_by_name('muxout')
```

to set the child element to async false, but I just can't see it - the muxout element (my label for splitmuxsink) does not have an async property.

Answer (score 1):

After correspondence with development team, I was told there was a bug in split muxsink which the developer corrected in 1.8.3. An update to 1.8.3 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the problems can be the format of SINK pad of mp4mux. **splitmuxsink** consists of **mp4mux** and **filesink** in the default configuration. In your pipeline you produce H264 with *stream-format=byte-stream* parameter, however, **mp4mux** expects only *stream-format=avc*.